# Windows Azure Endpoint not working

Tags: azure

I have a problem with my windows azure virtual machine.
I need to open the Port 443 (HTTPS) on the VM.
In the Endpoint Config. of the virtual machine, I opened it and configure the ACL with the following parameters:

```
Permit
0.0.0.0/0
```

It's a Windows Server 2012 VM and I created the firewall rule for the public Connection.
A Port Check from ping.eu shows that the port 443 is closed.

The Location of the virtual machine is Western Europe.

I hope, you can help me.

Kind Regards 
Sebastian

Comment: I wonder if it's the ACL rule.  By default an endpoint is open and only when you add a rule does it lock down.  Have you tried removing the ACL rule?

Comment: I've got the same problem - endpoint open and firewall rule set on vm but still cannot get through.  Did you even find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue and it was very annoying! I thought at first I was not setting up the SSL bindings correctly or that it was a certificate issue, then moved on to firewall issues. In the end it was the Azure endpoint at fault.

I had added the 443 endpoint, disabled local firewall and got nothing nothing. I got suspicious when I added a new endpoint on 8080, bound to https and it worked fine.

I deleted the 443 endpoint, shut the Azure VM down from the webinterface after shutting down the client. Created a new 443 endpoint and restarted the VM (I had already tried restarting my win2012r2 vm). It worked.

It must be a glitch in the networking stack of azure endpoints. You are not going mad!!

Hope that helps!
P

Answer (score 1):

Did you also configure the Endpoint Configuration through the web management portal to forward connections from the ext->int ports ?

Anything you change on the Win2k12 Virtual machine will just affect the VM itself. i.e. opening 443 in the firewall, or configuring routes etc...

But you also need to allow a connection forward from the cloudapp.net public IP address to the internal IP of the box. See the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: i have opened the port on the virtual machine and i have the same config as you in the endpoint configuration in Management Portal.

Comment: Disable the firewall completely (temporarily) on the Win2k12 box and see if it works. I'm guessing you have a conflicting rule somewhere or haven't opened it on the different public/private firewall profiles.

Comment: i disabled the firewall on the box... but its always the same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I think you just have to wait a while and it eventually opens up.  I've done port scans and show it's definitely not open externally...eventually they open up though.

Answer (score 0):

Another gotcha. In addition to setting up the Endpoint configuration, you need to enable IP Forwarding. This is disabled by default.

IP Forwarding can be found in the IP Configuration settings of the network interface.